# Bluetooth neckband connected for audio but not for microphone with react-native-incall-manager

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth, microphone, ios-bluetooth, react-native-webrtc

I'm trying to use [react-native-incall-manager](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-incall-manager) to hopefully be able to use different microphones in my app that uses `react-native-webrtc`. But when a bluetooth device is connected, it asks for the nearby devices permission (testing in Android with PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) and continues to use the phone's inbuilt mic instead of the one in the bluetooth device. I can hear a slight charge in the bluetooth earphones so I guess the audio is routed to those speakers ( cant test this cos the app only has the mic function and no audio to speaker function ).

So I'm wondering how to connect the microphone in the bluetooth device while connected.